# Reading an objects property results in Uncaught TypeError of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to contain html template and its data in an object and then use a function to insert the html to the page.

Not sure why I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined",

```js
// Takes in an HTML class name as target arg and an object as data arg
let updateUI = (target, data) => {
  // Finds the target element in HTML
  let targetElement = document.querySelector('.' + target);
  // Appends the data arg object's html property to the target element innerHTML
  targetElement.innerHTML = data.html;
};

// Review object contains the data for the html and the html template as properties
let review = {
  data: {
    title: 'Amazing pizza',
    rating: 10,
  },

  html: `
  <div>
  <p>${this.data.title}</p>
  <p>${this.data.rating}</p>
  </div>
  `,
};

updateUI('pizza-review', review);
```

```html
<div class="pizza-review"></div>
```

Comment: Please add Object So we can help you.

Comment: @ParthRaval Not sure what you mean by adding Object? The object is is there it's "review"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access property of an object during Initialization pharse.
Access it later:

```
let review = {
  data: {
    title: 'Amazing pizza',
    rating: 10,
  },
};

review.html =
  `
  <div>
  <p>${review.data.title}</p>
  <p>${review.data.rating}</p>
  </div>
  `
```